# UV unwrapping of Pool Deck

Tags: texturing, uv

I am doing the Pool Deck tutorial of the Architecture Academy (Blender Guru) and after having done the basic modelling I have started with the texturing of this "Pool Deck". When having done the texturing it should look abut this:

[image]

When Blender Guru has UV unwrapped the house he shows this:

[image]

But I made some errors in UV unwrapping I think because this is my result

[image]

I will attach my Blend file. What did I do wrong when unwrapping this house ?

[image]

Comment: I didn't do the lesson but the UV map misses one or several seams (as it seems there are 4 islands in example by Price and 2 in yours) and hence map is squashed, If you want to exactly follow his mapping then return to the marking seams stage

Comment: another point : you have some doubles. If you just "remove doubles", the situation is clarified

Comment: I removed the doubles and that helped. But somehow the side walls and back wall are still connected with the ceiling and I think the ceiling and those walls should be two uv islands. I updated the bled file. How make the walls and ceiling two unconnected islands ?

Comment: If you select one of these faces and Ctrl+L using the delimit by seam option, you will see what is connected and so what needs an additional seam.

Comment: Concretely, the under faces of the balcony are connected to the surrounding walls via faces that go to the back of the house

Comment: I must have sand in my eyes but I cannot find this "delimit by seam option". could you show me ?

Comment: I've no tool that allows me to upload the screen capture right now, but in the tools panel (T) of the 3DView, you have an option box at the bottom of this panel that contains options for almost any Blender's command. So included Ctrl+L (select linked) command. So select one bottom face of the balcony, Ctrl+L, then use "Delimit by seam" in this panel.

Comment: thanks. I now see the problem. should I make loop cuts in the balcony ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53187/discussion-between-lemon-and-old-man).